# Entity Framework, eager loading entites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, linq

I have 3 classes which I would like to 'talk' to each other on a ASP.NET MVC C# WEBAPI app. They are, **Item**, which can have only one **User** but the **User** can make multiple **Comments** on multiple **Item**s and a **Comment** can have multiple **User**s but only one **Item**

My classes are as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}  

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Important { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using angularJs front end, and so that I don't get a forever repeating loop I have configured the following:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

I'm using entity framework 6 and I want to Display **all items** including the **comments** and the **users who have commented**

I have read and feel? that Projection using Linq is probably best?

I have the following in my dbContext. (P.S, I've disabled LazyLoading, and including the System.Data.Entity namespace)

```
using(var _db = new dbContext)
{
   var model = _db.Items.Include(i=>i.Comments.Select(p=>p.User).Select(vm=>new ViewModelItem(){
     //here I think is where I would say.... 
     ViewModelItem.Name = x.Name,
     ViewModelItem.Description = x.Description,
     ViewModelItem.Comments = ///
     ViewModelItem.Comments.User.Name = ///
   })).ToList();

  return Ok(model);
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

So I want to display **All** the comments and include the **User** who *owns* the **Item** but also include **All** the comments for that Item, and all the **Users** who have commented on that Item.

Without causing an infinite loop.

If I'm not being clear, please ask me to clarify. Any help as always is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: From your model you have an Item field in each comments as well as a User.  This means All Comments could have both right?  If that's true, you already have everything you need by just querying the Comments collection. If the user or item fields are not mandatory then this query will work...     var Comments = AllComments.Where(p => p.Item != null && p.User != null);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your comments data is good this should do it.

```
    var model = db.Comment.Select(p=>
    new ViewModelItem { 
        Name =   p.User.Name,
        Comments=p,
        Description=p.Item.Description,
    });
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. With the solution you have provided, I end up with 3 items displayed, they are duplicated, and what I actually have is one item with 3 comments. Thank you

Comment: If you want to filter by Item, you have to determine the single item you want and add it to your viewmodels, then you can add another filter to the query .Where(q=>q.item.id==theItem)